# How to use R binaries with SparkR?

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I ran the sparkR script provided under SPARK_HOME/bin and got an error saying "R" is not found. This is because of the fact that I don't have R installed on the nodes. 
For some reasons I can not install on those nodes. Now what I am left with is, place the R executables on a shared directory which is accessible to all nodes. This way I can run ./sparkR on any of the nodes.
What I am interested to know is, how do I point spark-submit to pick R from the installation directory than from the environment.

Comment: I don't think you can simply put R to a shared directory for the executors

Comment: @cricket_007 Why not with R binaries? If "R" can be executed in shell

Comment: I guess you're right, but I was thinking for the same reason you can't install R (you don't have root permissions), I doubt you can change the PATH variable